# How to estimate the parametars of a transfer function with 2 poles and no zeros?

Tags: matlab, controls

I am new to matlab and I have a transfer function 1/(ms^2+ds) for the positon of an object experiencing a thrust, drag and gravitational force. I want to estimate m and d. I have the output data in the time domain but I'm not sure how I can estimate m and d using matlab.  I have tried the following :

```
x = data            %position in time domain
np = 2;
nz = 0;
sys = tfest(x,np,nz);

sys.Denominator
```

I am getting the following error message "Error using tfest
The "tfest" command cannot be used for time series data. Consider using "ar", "arx" or "armax" command."  I understand that I can't use time domain data in the s-domain but I am not sure how to fix this. I learnt that armax does not support the continuous time model estimation. How can I go about solving my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the input used to measure the output to the data object before calling tfest. The function requires at least one input and one output data series to operate.
If the input is not available, I suggest to either get a new simulation with input, or convert the time-domain data to frequency domain data assuming an impulse as input.